# Getting public IP address of a remote's desktop client

Tags: c++, winapi, rdp

I'm developing an application which runs on the remote server (Windows Server 2016-2019, Windows 10) when user is initiating a remote connection with RDP. I'm using C++ and Win API.

I'm trying to get **public IP** address of the Remote Desktop Client.
I used method [WTSQuerySessionInformationW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) with WTSInfoClass set to WTSClientAddress. Unfortunately it looks as this function returns **local ip** of the client's computer for instance 192.168.1.10 not the public one.

The scenario is that client is accessing a remote desktop from anywhere in the world (so not only from a local network).
In the Window's Event Viewer under Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager I can see the public ip address (Source Network Address).

Which function or mechanism can I use to get this ip address?

Comment: you need use `WinStationQueryInformationW` with `WinStationRemoteAddress`

Comment: It is not clear which public IP you are looking for.  The public IP of the machine that the RDP session is running on, or the public IP of the client that is connecting to the RDP session. `WTSClientAddress` returns the remote IP of the client that is connected to the session, which will be the client's public IP if the RDP connection is being established over the Internet.  Otherwise it will be the client's LAN IP.

Comment: @RbMm `WinStationQueryInformationW()` is deprecated.  And how does `WinStationRemoteAddress` differ from `WTSClientAddress` in `WTSQuerySessionInformation()`?  When calling from the server side, they both return the client's remote IP.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - `WinStationQueryInformationW` return **another** result than `WTSQuerySessionInformation`. i know this exactly, use in self solution. and `WinStationQueryInformationW` return actual client address.

Comment: @RbMm I've never heard of `WinStationQueryInformationW()` before today, and I have no way to test it over the Internet, only over a LAN. Can you provide an example of how `WinStationRemoteAddress` and `WTSClientAddress` report different results?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, can. i use this api in MFA credential provide in case rdp login. it give the same result as we can view in event log. when `WTSQuerySessionInformation` give wrong

Comment: @RbMm I meant, can you provide an example *using IP addresses*?  If a client connects to an RDP session over the Internet vs over a LAN, which IPs are reported by each API?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *In the Window's Event Viewer under... I can see the public ip address (Source Network Address).* - exactly this address return `WinStationRemoteAddress` - this is client ip which visible from our comp (not which reported by rdp client by self)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  @RemyLebeau I need the public IP of the client that is connecting to the RDP session, I checked and the WTSClientAddress is always local ip even if client is connecting over internet.

Comment: @PrzemSzer - because `WTSClientAddress` return address which report rdp client **by self**. when `WinStationQueryInformationW` returm ip address how it visible from target comp. the `WinStationQueryInformationW ` exactly what you need

Comment: So, `WTSClientAddress` is the client's IP *from the client's perspective*, while `WinStationRemoteAddress` is the client's IP *from the server's perspective*?  OK, that makes some sense, thanks.

Comment: Have fun dealing with firewalls, NAT gateways, VPNs etc...

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when we read about [`WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wts_client_address) structure

> *The client network address is **reported by the RDP client itself** when it connects to the server. **This could be different than the**
> **address that actually connected to the server**. For example, suppose
> there is a NAT between the client and the server. The client can
> report its own IP address, but the IP address that actually connects
> to the server is the NAT address. For VPN connections, the IP address
> might not be discoverable by the client. If it cannot be discovered,
> the client can report the only IP address it has, which may be the ISP
> assigned address. Because the address may not be the actual network
> address, it should not be used as a form of client authentication.*

for get actual network address from server view we can use [`WinStationQueryInformationW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa383827(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with [`WinStationRemoteAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/ce70794f-2138-43e8-bf6c-2c147887d6a2)- it return [`WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/5b5a44b3-155f-4159-aad9-794e97275a3f).

you can copy paste this declaration`s or all [*winsta.h*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/ce70794f-2138-43e8-bf6c-2c147887d6a2) (by unknown reason in not included to sdk)

for first look we can decide that [`WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/5b5a44b3-155f-4159-aad9-794e97275a3f) is the same as [`SOCKADDR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sockaddr-2) (`SOCKADDR_IN` and `SOCKADDR_IN6`) by layout. and we can do reinterpret cast pointer from [`WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/5b5a44b3-155f-4159-aad9-794e97275a3f) to [`SOCKADDR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sockaddr-2).

but this is critical error. structures have **different alignment** !

```
C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(SOCKADDR_IN, sin_port) == 2);
C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS, ipv4.sin_port) == 4);
C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(SOCKADDR_IN, sin_addr) == 4);
C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS, ipv4.in_addr) == 8);
```

for use `WinStationQueryInformationW` need link with *winsta.lib* or get it in runtime from *winsta.dll*

so final code can be next:

```
typedef enum _WINSTATIONINFOCLASS {
    // ...
    WinStationRemoteAddress = 29,
    // ...
} WINSTATIONINFOCLASS;

#define LOGONID_CURRENT     ((ULONG)-1)

typedef struct {
    unsigned short sin_family;
    union {
        struct {
            USHORT sin_port;
            ULONG in_addr;
            UCHAR sin_zero[8];
        } ipv4;
        struct {
            USHORT sin6_port;
            ULONG sin6_flowinfo;
            USHORT sin6_addr[8];
            ULONG sin6_scope_id;
        } ipv6;
    };
} WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS,
*PWINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS;

EXTERN_C
DECLSPEC_IMPORT
BOOLEAN
WINAPI
WinStationQueryInformationW(
                            _In_opt_ HANDLE hServer,
                            _In_ ULONG SessionId,
                            _In_ WINSTATIONINFOCLASS WinStationInformationClass,
                            _Out_writes_bytes_(WinStationInformationLength) PVOID pWinStationInformation,
                            _In_ ULONG WinStationInformationLength,
                            _Out_ PULONG pReturnLength
                            );

ULONG GetRdpClientAddressFromServerView()
{
    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;
    ULONG cb;

    union {
        SOCKADDR sa;
        SOCKADDR_IN sa4;
        SOCKADDR_IN6 sa6;
    };

    WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS ra;

    if (WinStationQueryInformationW(0, LOGONID_CURRENT, WinStationRemoteAddress, &ra, sizeof(ra), &cb))
    {
        switch (sa.sa_family = ra.sin_family)
        {
        case AF_INET:
            sa4.sin_port = ra.ipv4.sin_port;
            sa4.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ra.ipv4.in_addr;
            RtlZeroMemory(sa4.sin_zero, sizeof(sa4.sin_zero));
            cb = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            sa6.sin6_port = ra.ipv6.sin6_port;
            sa6.sin6_flowinfo = ra.ipv6.sin6_flowinfo;
            memcpy(&sa6.sin6_addr, &ra.ipv6.sin6_addr, sizeof(in6_addr));
            sa6.sin6_scope_id = ra.ipv6.sin6_scope_id;
            cb = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN6);
            break;
        default:
            dwError = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
        }

        if (dwError == NOERROR)
        {
            // assume that WSAStartup already called
            // WSADATA wd;
            // WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &wd);

            char AddressString[64];
            ULONG dwAddressStringLength = _countof(AddressString);
            if (WSAAddressToStringA(&sa, cb, 0, AddressString, &dwAddressStringLength) == NOERROR)
            {
                DbgPrint("client ip is %s\n", AddressString);
            }
            else
            {
                dwError = WSAGetLastError();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and example code. Does WinStationQueryInformationW supports Windows 2016, 2019 and Windows 10? Have you tried it there. I read in the documentation that only Windows 2012 is supported.

Comment: @PrzemSzer - i don`t know what you mean under "supported", but this api exist and fine work on all windows versions, including latest win10 build. documentation frequently lie to you

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked! Would you be willing to do paid consulting on this, e.g. a review of our code? Please email me at psz@astec.net if that’s a possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming for .NET, you can use cassia Nuget Packages.
https://github.com/danports/cassia

It provides an API to access remote desktop related information.